# Adding a label to the center south of a panel?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

The code below adds the label to the left south of the panel, and when I use set location with the label, the position does not change. Is there a way to make the label be in the center south of the panel without the need for an extra panel?

EDIT: the JFrame has a BorderLayout and adds the panel to CENTER

```
JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("label");
pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
pnl.add(lbl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: What exactly you got? Did you set layout for JFrame?

Comment: [Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem you need to set text align of label to center panel?
If so, try this:

```
JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("label", SwingConstants.CENTER); //Set text align
pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
pnl.add(lbl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
lbl.setBackground(Color.red);
lbl.setOpaque(true); //Test background
getContentPane().add(pnl);
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Yes, you need to set the JLabel to be center aligned (1+). However, there is no need for the second panel. Just add the label directly to the frame.